# Select one record, grab "n" records before it, and iterate through them to see if they're sequential

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So, I'd like to grab a record from a table of results. Let's say that this is our "sample" record.

Once I have the sample record, I'd like to grab 10 results down the table, and check to see if the sample is sequential within this list of 10 results.

So, if our sample record was 124, I'd like to grab the 10 records before it, and check to see if they follow the sequence of 123, 122, 121, 120, etc.

Once I know that the sample result is in fact sequential down to 10 records, I would like to insert that record into a different table for keeping.

I am using SQL Server and T-SQL to do this, and pulling my hair out trying to do so. If anyone could offer any advice, I would GREATLY appreciate it. Here's what I have so far (with some data removed), with no idea if I'm on the right track.

```
declare @TestTable as table (a char(15), RowNumber integer)
declare @SampleNumber as char(15)
        
insert into @TestTable (a, RowNumber) 
select top 10 
    [NUMBERS], 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by a) as RowNumber 
from [TABLE] 
where 
    [NUMBERS] like [CONDITIONS] 
order by [NUMBERS] desc
```

With this, I'm trying to grab the result and also a set of row numbers, allowing me to iterate through them based on that row number. But, I'm getting an "Invalid column name 'a'" error when running. Feel free to forget about that error and write something totally new though, because I don't even know if I'm on the right track.

Again, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at `lag` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Your source table will need to have an indexed field that you can order by.

Comment: Also, source table definition and sample data would help

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how well this would perform on a larger dataset, but as Peter Smith mentioned, this is possible by using `lag` to see what the value of the row x rows prior in an ordered window was, though be aware this will run for *all* rows in your table and return all those that meet the criteria, rather than randomly sampling:

```
-- Create a not quite sequential dataset
declare @t table(n int);
with n as
(
    select row_number() over (order by (select null)) as n
          ,abs(checksum(newid())) % 14 as r
    from sys.all_objects
)
insert into @t
select n
from n
where r > 2;

-- Output the original dataset
select *
from @t;

-- Only return rows that come after a certain number of sequential numbers
declare @seq int = 10;
with l as
(
    select n
          ,n - lag(n,@seq,null) over (order by n) as l
    from @t
)
select n
from l
where l = @seq;
```